# java (spring) create database diffs automatically

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, migration, liquibase

I'm seeking for same functionality in Java that present in PHP's Doctrine ORM.

I can describe an entity and the `doctrine:migrations:diff` console command will make me a fine migration which will generate SQL for updating the database schema. then I can update current database schema with new fields/tables etc running `doctrine:migrations:migrate`

But what's the same way to do it in Java? I've tried to do it with Flyway, but had no luck because it can't just get the entity and generate diff: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/648#issuecomment-64208848

So, I just tried to do it with liquibase, but don't understand how to do it.

I've tried to ask this question in #java room on irc.freenode.net, but the closest answer was "let hibernate create the schema and have liquibase extract it" (thank you, k5_)

but… how?

many sources say that I must use somewhat "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"… but how? what is it?

I'm surprised that there's no examples "for dummies" over internet for this important functionality

I think that it is a terrible way to write all migrations by hands and I just don't believe that there are no solutions exist

please, help me

thank you in advance!

**UPD**

In my particular case I'm using Hibernate, I have basic entities defined (with OneToMany, ManyToOne mappings)
I want to start on clean database and updating its schema with migrations.

So my goal is to generate this migrations automatically from entities descriptions compared to current database schema state.

**UPD 2**

The second closest answer is (thanks once again, k5_): "configure hibernate to create a schema when it doesnt exist (just add the configuration option you posted to the persistence.xml). Start the server it will create a schema in a database. Use the liquibase to extract the schema. Or use it to create a diff over two databases."

Comment: Your question is kind of broad. There are many ways to do it and which one is the best for you depends on many things. Are you already using hibernate? Do you already have entities defined (with JPA/Hibernate)? Do you already have an existing database? Or can you start zero-based? I would suggest to break your question down to smaller parts.

Comment: @SergeVelikan hi! did you find the answer for this? I just started using java spring boot, I tried liquidbase and flyway but cannot create a migration diff like in doctrine in symfony and typeorm in nodejs..